# Unable to install Box2D package

Tags: apt, package-management, packaging, opencv

If I try to run `sudo apt-get install python-box2d` I get this nonsensical error message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libcv-dev : Depends: libopencv-core-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libcvaux-dev : Depends: libopencv-core-dev but it is not going to be installed
 libopencv-calib3d-dev : Depends: libopencv-calib3d2.3 (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
 libopencv-contrib-dev : Depends: libopencv-contrib2.3 (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
 libopencv-features2d-dev : Depends: libopencv-features2d2.3 (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
 libopencv-flann-dev : Depends: libopencv-core-dev (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libopencv-flann2.3 (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
 libopencv-highgui-dev : Depends: libopencv-highgui2.3 (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
 libopencv-imgproc-dev : Depends: libopencv-core-dev (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
                         Depends: libopencv-imgproc2.3 (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
 libopencv-legacy-dev : Depends: libopencv-legacy2.3 (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
 libopencv-ml-dev : Depends: libopencv-core-dev (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libopencv-ml2.3 (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
 libopencv-objdetect-dev : Depends: libopencv-objdetect2.3 (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
 libopencv-video-dev : Depends: libopencv-video2.3 (= 2.3.1-7) but it is not going to be installed
 libplayerdrivers3.0 : Depends: libopencv-core2.3 but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libopencv-highgui2.3 but it is not going to be installed
                       Depends: libopencv-imgproc2.3 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

If I try to run the suggested `sudo apt-get -f install`, it tries to install all the above, but they all fail with errors like:

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libopencv-video2.3_2.3.1-7_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libopencv_video.so.2.3.1', which is also in package libopencv2.3 2.3.1+svn6514+branch23-12~oneiric
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
```

What's going on here? As far as I know, Box2D doesn't use any of these OpenCV packages (it's a 2D physics library whereas OpenCV is a vision-processing library), and even if it did, why are all the packages broken?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be the fault the crappy repository used by [Gazebo](http://gazebosim.org/). Apparently, it provides packages that conflict with those in the standard repo. I removed its PPA and uninstalled all broken packages and that resolved the error.

Answer (score 0):

manually delete all the OpenCV Libs and then try running the command below.

sudo dpkg -r libopencv*